# how to do asp.net TextBox data save to dynamic table sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

How to save date from ASP .NET to sql table according to the login user name (every user has got separate table with their name).
Text box data on button click event need to save to respective table

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make a different table for each user ? they can all be in the same table !

And the only way to make your code work seems to be using a query so you can give the user name as the table name, something like:

```
'Insert into ' + TextBox.Text + ' Values(...)'
```

But you'de better assemble all the users in one table, having them on different tables is not efficient at all !!

Comment: thanks, this code already tried. it was not working. this tables are not master table there are some calculation to be done with what ever the user is selected services items in the textbox. so multiple user data should not get clash before the final calculation

Comment: how many users are we talking about here ?
and the number of users will change or is it fixed ?
**Edit:** you're using ASP.Net with C# or VB ?

Comment: user are limited its about 4 members, using visual studio 2017

Comment: Then there is an easy way out, add a condition on users, and for each user you execute a query that have his table, `if userName = "UserA" then <instructions> elseif userName ) "UserB" then <instruction> etc...`.

Comment: In other words you'll be using C# (or VB according to wich one you're coding with) to solve this issue.